# Code coverage tool for tSQLt

Tags: sql-server, code-coverage, redgate, tsqlt

I am trying to test the code coverage for tSQLt.

I found a tool, SQL Cover, on the "DLM Automation Suite" site. There are some procedures which are encrypted in the database, so it throws an exception. Is it a limitation of that tool or is there an alternative way to test the code coverage of tSQLt test cases?

Comment: You can't measure source code coverage when the code is *encrypted* - there is no source code to cover! No code coverage tool will be able to calculate coverage without *decrypting* the source first. While it's easy to crach this encryption, it's much better to do so yourself, then encrypt the procedures again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I pushed a fix to SQLCover yesterday to skip over encrypted procs rather than crashing:

You won't get code coverage for encrypted procedures but there is now a "Warnings" property on the results showing any encrypted procs we skipped.

Ed